# Proof that the annulus $V=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n:s<\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert<r\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

It appears that I have some idea of how to do this proof, but I'm feeling lost in the maze with regards to how the epsilon should be used in the subsequent inequalities. Would appreciate some hints and/or clarifications.

**Problem**:
$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
Given that $V=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n:s<\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert<r\}$, where $s<r$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $s,r\in \mathbb{R}$, $\vec{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $V$ is open.

My version:

> Let $\varepsilon = \min\{r-\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a} \Vert, r-s-(r-\Vert \vec{x} -\vec{a}\Vert)\}=\min\{r-\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a} \Vert, \Vert \vec{x} -\vec{a}\Vert - s\}$, and let $\vec{x}\in V$. Then we must show that $B_\varepsilon\subset V$. Let $\vec{y}\in B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})$, such that $\Vert \vec{y}-\vec{x}\Vert < \varepsilon$. We need to show that $\vec{y}\in V$ by showing that $s<\Vert \vec{y}-\vec{a}\Vert < r$.
>
> (i) $||\vec{y}-\vec{a}||=||(\vec{y}-\vec{x})+(\vec{x}-\vec{a})||\leq ||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||+||\vec{x}-\vec{a}||<\varepsilon+||\vec{x}-\vec{a}||=r-\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert+\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert=r.$
>   (ii) $||\vec{y}-\vec{a}||=||\vec{x}-\vec{a}-(\vec{x}-\vec{y})||\geq ||\vec{x}-\vec{a}||-||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||>||\vec{x}-\vec{a}||-\varepsilon=\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert-\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{a}\Vert+s=s.$
>
> Therefore, $\vec{y}\in V$ and $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset V$.

I'm concerned as this proof looks somewhat clumsy. There are two possibilities for the epsilon, and I think that each possibility must satisfy the condition for $s$ and $r$, but how? Maybe something is wrong in my definition of the epsilon?

Comment: A shorter proof would go as follows: the intersection of two open sets is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost right. Here are comments.

First, you should start the proof by fixing $\mathbf{x}\in V$, rather than by defining $\epsilon$. Your choice of $\epsilon$ *depends* on $\mathbf{x}$, so your definition of $\epsilon$ is meaningless until you have fixed $\mathbf{x}$.

Second, you assume in (i) that $\epsilon=r-\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|$. This is obviously not right; $\epsilon$ is defined as the minimum of $r-\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|$ and $\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|-s$. However, this is no problem, because if $x=\min\left\{y,z\right\}$, then $x\leq y$ and $x\leq z$. (This is a very useful fact to have at your disposal for proofs in analysis.) So the correct deduction is that $\epsilon\leq r-\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|$. You just need to replace an equality by an inequality. You make a similar mistake in (ii).

Finally, let me critique some of your language.

When you say "Let $\mathbf{y}\in B_\epsilon(\mathbf{x})$, such that $\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|<\epsilon$," the phrase "such that" makes it sound as though you are imposing an *additional* condition on $\mathbf{y}$ beyond the fact that it is an element of the set $B_\epsilon(\mathbf{x})$. This is wrong. You could replace the words "such that" with the words "so that." Or, for even greater precision, you could say "Let $\mathbf{y}\in B_\epsilon(\mathbf{x})$; this means that $\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|<\epsilon$."

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Someone rightly noted that this is a proof of the case when $a = \mathbf{0}$. Since a norm is translation invariant, for some $a$ we may consider $x', y'$, where $x' = x + a, y' = y + a $.

What you gave was correct. Perhaps a "nicer" way: Let $|x - y| < \epsilon$. Then $$|y| = |(y - x) + x| \leq |x| + |y - x| < |x| + \epsilon \leq |x| + (s - |x|) = s .$$ Now by the reverse triangle inequality, $$ |y| = |x - (x - y)| \geq | |x| - |x - y| | > | |x| - (|x| - r) | = |r| = r . $$

Comment: You're wrong that the given proof is correct. Moreover, what you've written shows only that $y$ lies in the annulus centered at $0$, whereas the annulus in question is centered at $a$. This is not hard to fix, but something must be said to fix it.

Comment: Right you are. Edited it so as, if I didn't make any silly mistakes, to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier approach:

The function $f(x) = \|x-a\|$ is continuous and the set $(s,r)$ is open,
hence $V = f^{-1} ((s,r))$ is open.